# How to add a subview to a TableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, tableview

I need to add a subview to TableViewCell when the button in TableViewCell is clicked it should show another tableview as a subview and height of the tableview should be dynamic according to number of cell.

How can I do this?

[image: How can I do this]

Above screenshot is taken from a very popular shopping app and I need to do the same in my project.

Comment: Do you have all tableview cell that have one sub view like submenu ?

Comment: Search on github/google for "Expandable Table View", you will get solution

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya yes , i need to add subview or sub tableview  like above to each cell but the size of the sub tableview has to be dynamic according to the elements .

Comment: then you have to use expandable tableview and you will got it in https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ftfoldingtableview

Comment: @Shikha use that library folding tableview and you have to just set your main tableview as in this tableheaderview

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya alright lemme try :) thanks

Comment: ok @Shikha try it and tell me if any other problem you face then

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya sure :) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily achieve this using simple `UITableView`. For that you need to set all your main categories as your **UITableview section** and respected sub-categories can be added to respective **rowOfSection**.

Comment: that's not what i want

Comment: it is the solution, and better approach...adding as subview is not recommended.

Comment: @Shikha If you don't get the solution from this way then please explain more in detail that what is your requirement? Because as you have currently explained your problem, my suggested answer is the easiest and recommended way to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can use just one table view with UITableViewStyleGrouped style, and set "Men","Women","Kids & Baby" as TableView sections header, keep an boolean value to determine the result of "numberOfRowsInSection:" of each section and reload tableview.

Answer (score 0):

See the below link at github:

https://github.com/OliverLetterer/SLExpandableTableView

This contains the Expandable TableView, which you required. You have to implement `SLExpandableTableViewDelegate` and `SLExpandableTableViewDatasource` which contains different method, in which you have to provide inner tableview as well.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This should be a comment, until or unless, some part of code as effort is included as answer.

Comment: ya right @Mr.Bista that kind of solution post in comment not in answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some work on your own I can give the directions that'll give you a way from my point of view :-

1. Make a Custom cell which you want to expand.
2. While designing the cell make its height in storyboard like 200 or so according to your need and add all the elements those you want to see when the cell is expanded.
3. You'll need two delegate methods first -didSelectItemAtIndexPath and second HeightForRowAtIndexPath at index path.
4. First You need to make sure the user taps on the button or cell that you want to expand , and to achieve that you need to call didSelectItemAtIndexPath.
5. Once you get your cell Position, in HeightForRowAtIndexPath check the indexpath is equal to your cell's indexpath,if yes then return the exact height(ie:200) of your cell otherwise return the default(ie:70) height of you cell.

> **Note** : In didSelectItemAtIndexPath you need to call to method to update the current cell

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```